# How to specify the number of columns using integer in 'paste (shell)'?

Tags: bash, shell

### Input

Here is the variable `myinputs` in shell (BASH).

```
1
2
3
4
... (Over than 100,000 lines)
```

### Expected Output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... (until to 1000)
1001 1002 1003 1004 ... (until to 2000)
2001 2002 2003 2004 ... (until to 3000)
```

### Original Method

I used the `paste` and its delimiter list like below,

```
lines=$(paste -d " " \
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \
< $myinputs)
```

### My Problem

Is any method can make the code more clever?

```
# Maybe like this.
lines=$(paste --columns 1000 < $myinputs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I just tested with `10`, you may change it to `1000`

Using `xargs`

```
$ xargs -n10 < infile
```

Using `awk`

```
$ awk 'ORS=NR%10?OFS:RS' infile
```

Example:

```
$ seq 100 | xargs -n10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100


$ seq 100 | awk 'ORS=NR%10?OFS:RS'
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{printf("%d%s",$0,$0%1000==0?RS:FS)}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Seems not working. May I ask what is the variable `$i`?

Comment: I entered `awk '{printf("%d%s",$0,$i%1000==0?RS:FS)}' ./mydata.txt`. But I get massive lines with `0`.

Comment: @Husky, apologies I had a typo in code, I fixed it now, please check now and let me know on same then.

Comment: @Husky, yes please. So your Input shown is not same as you are passing?

Comment: For this moment, output is same with input. (One line with one data)

Comment: I have same data as your post have and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I think your answer is perfect. But I'm confused why my real data not working. I will try more.

Comment: @Husky, See if you having carriage characters in your data by doing `cat -v Input_file` let me know if that shows ^M characters etc in output?

Comment: Dear sir @RavinderSingh13, I try to modify your answer like `awk '{printf("%s%s",$0,NR%1000==0?RS:FS)}' ./mydata.txt` and works for me. I understood that you use the `$0` to mod 1000 to identify the line number, so I change it to line number.

Comment: I will make a summary later include this parts. Thanks your helps much.

Answer (score 1):

**Using PR all is easy**

```
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ lines="$(pr -a --column 10 -t -S" " -J list.txt)"
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ echo "$lines"
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$
```

**In your case**

```
lines="$(echo "$myinputs" | pr -a --column 1000 -W 10000 -t -S" " -J)"

-a        print lines horizontally
--column  number of columns
-t        omit page headers and trailers
-S / -J   use space instead of tabs as line delimiter
-W        set page width
```

Comment: Almost working ! But I get an error when I modified the column up to 1,000. `pr: page width too narrow`

Comment: It's a perfect answer for my case. Is any method can ignore the limit of page width?

Comment: Remember that page width must to be always greatest of column number and all will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Should you define a function:

```
mycols() {
  local i max
  local -a cols=( )

  max=$1
  shift

  for ((i=0; i<max; i++ )); do
    cols+=( - )
  done

  paste "$@" "${cols[@]}"
}
```

...then with it defined, use becomes as simple as:

```
lines=$(mycols 100 -d ' ' <"$myinputs")
```